# подскажите пожалуйста можно ли сжать код?

Tags: python

```
playsound('1.mp3')

playsound('2.mp3')

playsound('3.mp3')

playsound('4.mp3')

playsound('5.mp3')

playsound('6.mp3')

playsound('7.mp3')

playsound('8.mp3')

playsound('9.mp3')

playsound('10.mp3')

playsound('11.mp3')

playsound('12.mp3')

playsound('13.mp3')

playsound('14.mp3')

playsound('15.mp3')

playsound('16.mp3')

playsound('17.mp3')

playsound('18.mp3')

playsound('19.mp3')

playsound('20.mp3')

playsound('21.mp3')

playsound('22.mp3')

playsound('23.mp3')

playsound('24.mp3')

playsound('25.mp3')

playsound('26.mp3')

playsound('27.mp3')

playsound('28.mp3')

playsound('29.mp3')

playsound('30.mp3')

playsound('31.mp3')

playsound('32.mp3')

playsound('33.mp3')

playsound('34.mp3')

playsound('35.mp3')

playsound('36.mp3')

playsound('37.mp3')

playsound('38.mp3')

playsound('39.mp3')

playsound('40.mp3')

playsound('51.mp3')

playsound('52.mp3')

playsound('53.mp3')

playsound('54.mp3')

playsound('55.mp3')

playsound('56.mp3')
```

Comment: `for i in range(1, 57): playsound(f'{i}.mp3')`

Comment: Вы как будто про циклы не слышали :)

Comment: слышал, но не знал как можно сюда вставить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(1, 57):
    playsound("{}.mp3".format(i))
```